# How to tell Spring Data MongoDB to store nested fields of a document that are also documents in their own collection?

Tags: spring, mongodb, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

I have two collections called `persons` and `addresses`. The idea is to have person hold an address in the field `address`. I use Spring Data MongoDB to persist those mentioned documents.

My usual way of crafting the "relation" between Person > Address was to store the ID of the address and give it to the person object. Later when I `find()` a person I resolve the address object by it's id and voila I have my person + address.

However I find this somewhat every cumbersome since in my code I just want to add the `Address` object as whole and not only it's ID so I can work with it while also saving it to the repository at any point of time.

I therefore started a little unit test to see how Spring Data MongoDB saves the `Address` object if it's just a field of `Person` and is not saved by it's own `Repository`.

This is what I came up with:

```kotlin
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository

@Document("person")
data class Person(
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val age: Int,
    var address: Address
)

@Document("addresses")
data class Address(
    val id: String,
    val street: String?,
    val number: Int?
)

@Repository
interface PersonRepository : MongoRepository<Person, String>

@Repository
interface AddressRepository : MongoRepository<Address, String>
```

And this is the unit test - that fails with the last steps as I was expecting:

```kotlin
internal class FooTest @Autowired constructor(
    private val personRepository: PersonRepository,
    private val addressRepository: AddressRepository
) {

    @Test
    fun `some experiment`() {
        val testPerson = Person("001", "Peter", 25, Address("011","Lumberbumber", 12))
        personRepository.save(testPerson)

        val person = personRepository.findAll()[0]

        assertThat(person).isNotNull
        assertThat(person.address).isNotNull
        assertThat(person.address.street).isEqualTo("Lumberbumber")
        assertThat(person.address.number).isEqualTo(12)
        // works because address was just copied into the object structure
        // of `person` and was not seen as a standalone document

        val address = addressRepository.findAll()[0]

        assertThat(address.street).isEqualTo("Lumberbumber") // fails
        assertThat(address.number).isEqualTo(12) // fails
        // As expected `address` was not persisted alongside the `person` document.

    }
}
```

So I thought about using `AbstractMongoEventListener<Person>` to intercept the saving process and pick the `Address` object out from Person here and do a `addressRepository.save(addressDocument)` while putting a lightweight address object (only having the ID) back in the `Person` document.
The same I'd to in the reverse when doing a find for Person and assembling Person and Address together again.

```kotlin
@Component
class MongoSaveInterceptor(
    val addressRepository: AddressRepository

) : AbstractMongoEventListener<Person>() {
    override fun onBeforeConvert(event: BeforeConvertEvent<Person>) {
        val personToSave = event.source
        val extractedAddress = personToSave.address
        val idOfAddress = addressRepository.save(extractedAddress).id
        personToSave.address = Address(idOfAddress, null, null)
    }

    override fun onAfterConvert(event: AfterConvertEvent<Person>) {
        val person = event.source
        val idOfAddress = person.address.id
        val foundAddress = addressRepository.findById(idOfAddress)
        foundAddress.ifPresent {
            person.address = it
        }
    }
}
```

It works that way and might be a workaround solution for my requirement.

**BUT**

I feel that there has to be something like that already working and I might just need to find the proper configuration for that.

That's where I am stuck atm and need some guidance.

Comment: `@Document("addresses")` - The `addresses` is a different collection?

Comment: The idea is to split `person` and `address` into two separate collections. Please don't ask for the reason since this is a minimum example and I did not want to bloat the questions with details of the concept behind the requirement

Comment: I am just reading about @DBRef that looks exactly what I need. I will restate an answer if it works the way I need it to.

Comment: I think the design should be that the address is embedded within the person document. This is one of the main features on the document model. Having an address collection is not recommended. See this [Data Model Design](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/core/data-model-design/index.html). It goes with the principle that the related data should be stored together and can be accessed together.

Comment: @prasad_ The problem with that approach is if I want to change the 'address' I have to change it in every document where it is embedded in to have a consistency. I know that this is a thing relational databases solve by design but since I want MongoDB for it's other features and not it's document design I have no other way than returning to relational design

Answer (score 1):

Another research showed me it's about `@DBRef` (https://www.baeldung.com/cascading-with-dbref-and-lifecycle-events-in-spring-data-mongodb) I have to use. This way Spring Data MongoDB stores the embedded document class and resolves it when loading the parent document object from the database.